# android studio: how to update data of a list View made using custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, custom-adapter

I have a list view made using custom Adapter & contains 2 text view in each row, 
I want to update data of  rows , when I long pressed on row.

Comment: change data in onLongPress and  call notifyDataSetchanged() method

Comment: @user6299305 you can share code snippet also, if you want more clarity..!

Answer (score 2):

Just update your model object according to the need and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in`OnLongClickListener` or `OnItemLongClickListener` of ListView. List data will update.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your custom adapter, and set an `OnLongClickListener` on the view you return in `getView()`. In the `OnLongClickListener` update the array or list you are using and when finished, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
```